# androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle' is deprecated

Tags: android, androidx, actionbardrawertoggle

I use androidx library and i have androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle' is deprecated error in the following code:

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // associate Navigation Drawer with ActionBar
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
```

How do i suppose to change it? I tried to find a solution but nothing has to do with androidx. I would apriciate an easy explanation as i m new in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change androidx.**legacy**.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle to androidx.**appcompat**.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle, i.e. legacy to appcompat.

Also, remember to add your toolbar as your third argument.

Documentation can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle